# Navbar en bootstrap no es fixed-top ni justifica texto a la derecha

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando la version de bootstrap 4.0 y he hecho una barra de navegacion, pero quiero los nav-link o elementos a la derecha y que la barra sea fixed top, he intetado de todas formas pero no sirve.

el codigo:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg ">


            <img src="imagenes/logopeque.png" class="d-sm-none"> 
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-align-right"> </i></span>
             </button>
        <div class="navbar-header">

             <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="#"><img src="imagenes/logo.png"><img src="imagenes/texto.png"> </a>
                  </div>



        <div class="container">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="nav-navbar ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">&ensp;&ensp;INICIO</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">&ensp;&ensp;¿QUIENES SOMOS?</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&ensp;&ensp;SERVICIOS <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
                <li class="nav-item" id="thisone"><a href="#" class="nav-linksito"> &ensp;ction</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="thisone"><a href="#" class="nav-linksito"> &ensp;nother action</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item" id="thisone"><a href="#" class="nav-linksito"> &ensp;ction</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="thisone"><a href="#" class="nav-linksito"> &ensp;nother action</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> &ensp;&ensp;EVENTOS </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">&ensp;&ensp;CONTACTO </a></li>
          </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

mi css:

```
nav{
    background-color::#232323 !important;

}

.navbar-toggler{
    background-color:#2B2BF5 !important;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon{
    color:orange !important;
    top:6px !important;
}
.nav-link{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif',serif !important;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    }
.nav-link:hover{
    color:#FF8552 !important;
}
.nav-linksito{
    font-family:'Bree Serif', serif !important;
    color:white !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
}
.nav-linksito:hover{
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color:#2b2bf5 !important;
}
```

¿Alguien podria orientarme?

Comment: Hola @Angel Gomez Cómo no soy fuerte usando Twitter-Bootstrap no te puedo orientar directamente. Sólo puedo indicarte que en tus estilos tienes errores de asignación usas '::' dónde sólo debiera aparecer ':' `background-color::#232323 !important;`para asignar valores de atributos. Te sugiero hacer el [tour] para enterarte de cómo funcionamos. Y, para tu pregunta ver: [NavBars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navs.asp)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia estimado :-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira si no te funciona la propiedad de Bootstrap

Prueba dándole directo al CSS

nav{ position: fixed !important;}

Con eso quedará fijo en top, espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.